# Firebase: How many snapshot listeners is my query causing?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Firebase has a limit of 100 snapshot listeners per client. I have a Screen called "MyChats" which displays all the chats a user has and wanted to know the following:

1. Is my below function, which gets the data for the screen, counting as just a single listener?
2. Would grabbing the latest message for each chatroom (to list it in a preview, similar to Whatsapp, FB Messenger and other chat applications) affect my number of listeners?

```
firestore
  .collection("chats")
  .where("membersArray", "array-contains", currentUser.uid)
  .where("deletedAt", "==", null)
  .orderBy("lastMessage.date")
  .startAt(new Date())
  .onSnapshot(...);
```

[image: Here is a screenshot of the data structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is my below function, which gets the data for the screen, counting as just a single listener?

You are calling `onSnapshot()` only once so that's only 1 listener.

> Would grabbing the latest message for each chatroom affect my number of listeners?

If you are referring to above code, that's just a single query with 1 listener. If you individually add a listener for each document then that'll be N listeners.

```
const col = db.collection("chats");

// 1 listener irrespective of number of documents in collection
col.onSnapshot(...)


// 3 listeners, as they are assigned separately
col.doc("1").onSnapshot(...)
col.doc("2").onSnapshot(...)
col.doc("3").onSnapshot(...)
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the latest message for each chatroom without using a listener? Otherwise a chat app could easily hit the limit of 100.

Comment: @cipano can you please update your question with screenshots of your Firestore structure so I know what and how a chatroom is stored?

Comment: Sure, just updated it.

Comment: @cipano like the listener should trigger every time a new message is added in sub-collection of those chats? You can use listener with a [CollectionGroup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) query. `collectionGroup('messages').where(<check for user ID?>).onSnapshot(... )`